# PM2 environment variables with React.js

Tags: reactjs, pm2

i have this ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'web',
      script: 'serve',
      watch: true,
      port: 80,
      env: {
        PM2_SERVE_PATH: '/var/www/web',
        PM2_SERVE_PORT: 80,
        PM2_SERVE_SPA: 'true',
        PM2_SERVE_HOMEPAGE: '/index.html',
        REACT_APP_TEST: 'password',
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and i start with **pm2 start ecosystem.config.js**

but in react app this "REACT_APP_TEST" is undefined.

what am i doing wrong? I looked in the documentation and I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You can add  ```--update-env``` to pm2 start if env is not read in the process. ```pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --update-env```.